# Export data as a json from google sheet Automatically

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to export the query the data in the Google sheet and export the result as json output. I would like to run this script automatically every day. Can it be done using "Appscripts"?
Or is there a better way. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
function exporttojson() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const vsjs = JSON.stringify(vs)
  Logger.log(vsjs);
  return vsjs;
}
```